# Good way to store multiple variables in Java?

Tags: java

Let's say I have these monsters (already configured their names, attack, level, exp, etc) but what's a good way to keep track of their X and Y?

Maybe an `ArrayList<>`? Like add in that arraylist `1|12|8|3` where `1` is the ID of Monster (to later use as m`1`.gif, 12 is X and 8 is Y and 3 is map number.

What do you think is a good way to store monsters in the map in Java?

Comment: Get a good book that introduces Object-Oriented Programming. If you take learning programming seriously, it will be very much worth it. --Happy programming!

Comment: Why? OOP sounds like the ideal answer, and we have to assume you're unfamiliar with it since you're not using it. Rather than being offended, why not take the unanimous advice to heart? Every answer suggests the same thing: A `Monster` class.

Comment: Sorry Jahkr, I was not trying to offend. Did you think I was implying that you don't take programming seriously? Maybe I should have worded it differently. I was simply trying to say that it is a very important concept for any serious programmer to learn. An object-oriented programming structure is the answer to your question. There are many books that introduce OOP with Java or C++. You should look into it. A good OOP book will be worth the time and money to someone who takes it seriously.

Answer (score 7):

Well you certainly wouldn't want to take advantage of Encapsulation by using Objects in an Object Oriented Language.

```
class Monster 
{
  private String myName;
  private int attack;
  private int level;
  private int experience;
  public Monster(String n, int att, int lvl, int e)
  {
      myName = n;
      attack = att;
      level = lvl;
      experience = e;
  }

  // other useful methods go here!
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you describe, simply storing a few `int`s, is a **code smell** called "[Primitive Obsession](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html)".

The generally better solution is coming up with an object to **mean what you want it to mean**. For example, you can have a `Map` where the keys are a monster and the values are a **`MapPoint`s** (X, Y and map ID).

In general, you should start thinking in objects and *naming* these concepts you want to use.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to create a 'Monster' class that will hold your variables.

A quicker duck tape way would be to use a regular array instead of an ArrayList if you're only storing four variables.

```
int[] monster1 = { 1, 12, 8, 3 };
```

And to access them:

```
int id = monster1[0];
```